# Trying to get Sublime Text 3 working from terminal

Tags: terminal, bash, sublimetext

I am trying to get the Sublime Text to work with Git from the following tutorials
http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/osx_command_line.html and https://help.github.com/articles/associating-text-editors-with-git#using-sublime-text-as-your-editor

I created a bin directory with `mkdir ~/bin` and run the line `ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl` I have then tried the command `subl --help` but get the following error

```
-bash: subl: command not found
```

If I go to my Finder I can see subl in the bin folder in my username. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `~/bin` to your `PATH` variable. In Terminal, type `cd` to return to your home directory. Then, type `bin/subl .profile` to open your `~/.profile` file. If it doesn't exist, Sublime will just create an empty file. Add this line to it:

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

and save the file. Close out of Sublime, and restart Terminal. You now should be able to use the `subl` command from any directory.